# generate center frequency for sin wave in python

Tags: python, for-loop, operator-keyword, frequency

I implement spreading function in the psychoacoustic model.
My steps:

1. Generate center frequency of each Bark
2. Group subband frequency to Bark group
3. Calculate power of each critical band
4. Convert to dB

I started with step 1 and got a syntax error in python.
I have no idea how to correct

```
# Generate center frequency of each Bark
center = zeros(1, size(bark_scale, 2) - 1)
for k in  1:size(bark_scale, 2) - 1:
    center(k) = (bark_scale(k) + bark_scale(k + 1)) / 2
end
```

**Edit:**

```
# Generate center frequency of each Bark
center = zeros(1, bark_scale.size[1]- 1)
k = np.arange(bark_scale.size[1] - 1)
center = (bark_scale[k] + bark_scale[k + 1]) / 2
```

**Edit+corrections**

Comment: Your code looks more like Matlab code than Python code. For example `size(bark_scale, 2)` works for Matlab and `bark_scale.size[1]` is the equivalent in Python. You should revise the syntax of your whole code.

Comment: @Flabetvibes   how can I rewrite this from Matlab ti python?

    bark_scale=zeros(1,size(z,2)*2)
    for k=2:2:size(z,2)*2

Comment: `bark_scale = zeros(1, size(z, 2) * 2) for k = 2:2:size(z, 2) * 2` doesn't seem correct. For the first part, you can rewrite `bark_scale = zeros(1, size(z, 2) * 2)` with `bark_scale = np.zeros((1, z.size[1] * 2))`.

Comment: I will not be able to help regarding Bark scale generation but I can help you regarding Python syntax. Please edit your question to update your code and mention what is the exact Python error you get. It will be easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to correct your code. I assume that `bark_scale` is an array of shape `(1, n)` and is loaded with `numpy`.

**Numpy** First you need to import `numpy` to be able to handle arrays:

```
import numpy as np
```

**Array size** To get the size of the second dimension of an array (e.g. `bark_scale`), you should use `bark_scale.size[1]` instead of `size(bark_scale, 2)`.

**Array filled with zeros** To define an array filled with zeros, you should use `np.zeros((1, 10))` instead of `zeros(1, 10)`.

**For loop** In Matlab, it looks like this:

```
for k = 1:10
    % ...
end
```

whereas in Python it looks like:

```
for k in range(0, 10):
    # ...
```

**Array access** You should use `bark_scale[k]` instead of `bark_scale(k)` to get the k-th value of `bark_scale`.

With all these points you should be able to correct your code. I hope this will help you.